# Changing token value in ANTLR4 lexer

Tags: antlr4

I'm trying to parse a language in ANTLR4 that is case-insensitive as far as identifiers go.  If possible I'd like to push this onto the lexer, something like:

`IDENT : [a-zA-Z]+  { /* set token = token.toUpper() */ }`

Except I can't find anything in the documentation that would let me change a token's value in a lexer action and looking at the generated code it doesn't look like there's anything exposed in a lexer action that would permit this.

Am I missing something or do I need to handle this in the application code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
IDENT : [a-zA-Z]+ { setText(getText().toUpperCase()); };
```

It seems to be the proposed way, a similar example is [here](https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=5373959)

Comment: With C#, it's a property Text in this case (instead of a C#ized SetText() method).